# Conditionally show HTML in a DevExpress MVC gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I want to show an image in a cell in a DevExpress MVC gridview, but only when the bound field has the value 'true'.

This is the code I created, but this show the image always, and what I want to accomplish is that it is conditionally shown on the VALUE of the property of the bound object.

Question is: how can I get / read the value of the objects' property here?

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
        {

            settings.Columns.Add(column =>
            {
                column.Caption = "filter";
            });


            settings.Columns.Add(column =>
            {

                //show images/archive16.png if archived
                column.Caption = Resources.Fault.Archived;
                column.SetDataItemTemplateContent("<img src=\"/images/archive16.png\" />");
            });
```

Comment: Can you do something like this: `column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(cell => cell.Text == "true" ? "This is true!" : "this is false")`?

Comment: This gives me a syntax error?

Comment: Which part is in error?

Comment: It may need braces: `column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(cell => { cell.Text == "true" ? "This is true!" : "this is false" });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of puzzling, I found out this is the solution:

```
 settings.Columns.Add(column =>
            {
                column.Caption = "archiveren";
                column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
                {
                    ViewContext.Writer.Write("<input type=\"button\" value=\"archive\" />");
                });


            });
```